# Adding Analytics Message Tracer to wso2 api manager 1.10

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to add the feature Analytic Message Tracer in wso2 am 1.10. But while installing I am getting error as mentioned below,

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Analytics Message Tracer Handler Aggregate Feature 1.1.0 (org.wso2.carbon.analytics.message.tracer.handler.feature.group 1.1.0) Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.3) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.8 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.8) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.9 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.9) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.1) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.2 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.2) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.3) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.4 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.4) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.7 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar 4.4.7) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Analytics Message Tracer Handler Aggregate Feature 1.1.0 (org.wso2.carbon.analytics.message.tracer.handler.feature.group 1.1.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.4.7,4.5.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.3) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.4.3] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.7 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.4.7] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.8 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.8) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.4.8] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.4.9 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.4.9) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.jar [4.4.9]

Can any one please suggest me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Adding to the above comment, I have downloaded the p2-repo for the wso2 api manager 1.10 from the below mentioned link and created the repository locally and tried to add the feature but still no luck facing the same issue

Comment: Also i tried to add the feature Analytics Message Tracer Handler Aggregate Feature 1.0.1. for that I am getting error as mentioned below,

 Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Analytics Message Tracer Handler Aggregate Feature 1.0.1 (org.wso2.carbon.analytics.message.tracer.handler.feature.group 1.0.1) requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.3.0,4.4.0)' but it could not be found